# I want Run the infinite loop

Tags: sql-server

1-Using SQL Server 2014, how can I edit this code?
2-If the condition is not met Return to  condition check again
3-If the check condition is correct - go to Next
4-When you finish code Return to first condition check again
I want Run the infinite loop
Please see the picture for clarification[enter image description here](https://c.top4top.net/p_7614sfwl1.jpg)

```
    if not exists (
           select top 1 1 
            from sms.dbo.m_link
                 where link_check = 0
                )RETURN 
          WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
      INSERT INTO sms.dbo.M_Out (MessageTo ,MessageType ,Gateway ,UserId) 
      select top 1 1 link_MessageTo ,link_MessageType ,link_Gateway ,link_UserId  
                  from sms.dbo.m_link
                 where link_check = 0
              WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
```

Comment: Take out the return? Seriously, this question lacks any kind of hint as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How can I meet these conditions?
1-If the condition is not met Return to  condition check again
2-If the check condition is correct - go to Next
3-When you finish code Return to first condition check again

Please see the picture for clarification https://c.top4top.net/p_7614sfwl1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With your image and the update to your question, it looks like you are queuing records into the m_link table, and wanting to insert one record at a time into the m_out table? I'm not sure this is the best approach but to answer your question, you could use a `While Loop` which is often a dirty word in SQL Server.

The code logic you currently have is off, to sql it reads:

> if not exists (no record to be inserted)
>
> wait a few seconds
>
> insert the first record from the table that doesn't have any records into 
>   the outgoing table. (illogical)
>
> wait a few more seconds
>
> on the other hand, if a record **does** exists SQL does nothing, you haven't told it what you want to do

My suggestion of using the `while loop` is based on being able to complete the task as you have presented it, I am hesitant to suggest it as I doubt it is the best approach, however with out additional information the following code should accomplish what it seems you are trying to do.

without further ado:

```
set nocount on;

--| Supporting Tables
declare @delete as table (
    m_linkID int not null
);

declare @m_Out as table (
    m_OutID int identity(73,1) not null primary key clustered
,   m_linkID int not null
,   link_MessageTo nvarchar(255) not null
,   link_MessageType int not null
,   link_Gateway int not null
,   link_UserID int not null
);

declare @m_link as table (
    m_linkID int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   link_MessageTo nvarchar(255) not null
,   link_MessageType int not null
,   link_Gateway int not null
,   link_UserID int not null
);

--| populate the m_link table with example records
insert into @m_link (link_MessageTo, link_MessageType, link_Gateway, link_UserID)

select 'Message One', 1, 42, 666 union all
select 'Message Two', 1, 57, 99;

--| show the inserted records
select *
  from @m_link

--| evaluate the table for records (Start - While Loop)
 while exists (
                select 1
                  from @m_link
                )

begin
    --| 'move' records into the m_out table
    insert into @m_out (m_linkID, link_MessageTo, link_MessageType, link_Gateway, link_UserID)
    output inserted.m_linkID
      into @delete

    select top 1 m_linkID
         , link_MessageTo
         , link_MessageType
         , link_Gateway
         , link_UserID
      from @m_link

    --| remove the record from the m_link table
    delete 
      from @m_link
     where m_linkID in (
                        select m_linkID
                          from @delete
                          )

end;

select *
  from @m_Out

select *
  from @m_link
```

### Previous Answer prior to Ops Question Update

you might tag with the version of SQL Server you're using, and explain in more detail the over all scenario and goal.

You could try this:

```
   if not exists (
                    select 1
                      from sms.dbo.m_link
                     where link_check = 0
                    )
```

My concern is you are trying to implement a RBAR solution in a set based world. If you are trying to do X based on a row having Y, the approach is wrong.

Comment: Why do you need top 1 inside exists? And top 1 1? Why not top 1 *? That syntax always throws me for a loop (no pun intended).

Comment: I want to know if the predicate exists in the table, I don't care if it has more than a single instance of it, top 1 '1' (second 1) makes the result set a binary because I don't care about the record set that comes back. I explain to all Devs, I 'DO NOT 'select *' in production code', and this allows me to not do that even though it doesn't matter to the optimizer, I don't want someone say'n you put 'select *' in prod code ....

Comment: Inside an exists is the only time using * is perfectly fine. Exists only checks for the existence of a row. You can just as easily check for 1/0 which works just fine with an exists. As such, TOP is also not needed because exists returns immediately when it finds a row.

Comment: Gail Shaw has a great blog post about using TOP with EXISTS. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/04/05/to-top-or-not-to-top-an-exists/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll edit my answer; Form is important, I will not capitulate to select * in production code, not because of performance citations, because other people do not understand the difference.

Comment: I don't blame you there at all. Using * can cause some challenges with code checkers like SQLCop and such too. Sorry I didn't mean to be busting your chops at all. TOP 1 1 always makes me stop and look because it just looks so odd. Sort of like this. select top 1 1 [1] from sys.tables :)

Comment: I can't up-vote comments yet, or I would for the link. I enjoy the learning, I don't mind discourse at all.

Comment: Thank you I'm learning from you - How can I meet these conditions?
1-If the condition is not met Return to  condition check again
2-If the check condition is correct - go to Next
3-When you finish code Return to first condition check again Please see the picture for clarification  https://c.top4top.net/p_7614sfwl1.jpg